# Jmeter passed cookies to different thread group but still get requests with [no cookies]

Tags: multithreading, cookies, jmeter, transfer, cookiemanager

I have a question where I saw lots of various questsions and answers about this but nothing worked for me so far.

**Please read it to the end to see it's not a duplicated post**.

I'm using 2 thread groups which are using cookies. Since cookies are not being shared across thread groups, I used the method to "export" them into properties and "import" them back in the 2ns thread group with the coookie class of the CookieManager.
I placed the same http request on the 1st and 2nd thread groups. Obviously it works on the first, but on the 2nd, I see it uses **[no cookies]**.

The test structure is as follows:

```html
HTTP Cookie Manager
Thread A - 1 thread, 1 loop
 - Login page
    - Beanshell PostProcessor
        props.put("ASPXAUTH_Cookie","${COOKIE_.ASPXAUTH}");
        props.put("ASP.NET_SessionId_Cookie","${COOKIE_ASP.NET_SessionId}");
    - Page X to hit - success
Thread B - 6 thread, 1 loop
 - Login page
    - Beanshell Prerocessor
        import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.CookieManager;
        import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.Cookie;
        import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy;
        HTTPSamplerProxy sampler = ctx.getCurrentSampler();
        CookieManager manager = sampler.getCookieManager();
        Cookie cookie1 = new Cookie(".ASPXAUTH",props.get("ASPXAUTH_Cookie"),"","/",false,0);
        manager.add(cookie1);
        Cookie cookie2 = new Cookie("ASP.NET_SessionId",props.get("ASP.NET_SessionId_Cookie"),"","/",false,0);
        manager.add(cookie2);
    - Same Page X to hit - failure
```

First results for page X:

```js
GET http://Mysite/pages/MyView.aspx?subRoute=views&pageid=7168&routeName=dashboards

Cookie Data:
.ASPXAUTH=9CB09DD7A906ED67027E9B1ED71C707A498B8234C737169AA3EF1164890A217D9CCD1F1B32736338A7DFBF3DE0A07AD45F170A0F11FE49C827581C584577372D2D3C7D4F52DE1B73D3DE9A1263150B85F302DD01B9CF93AF380F5C63F618634CEEB5C3CFD95F1081EC28F5A556B21EAA; ASP.NET_SessionId=rg4dxqm1xai4wovvfvyezggo

Request Headers:
Connection: keep-alive
X-DevTools-Emulate-Network-Conditions-Client-Id: 08a74297-b666-496a-a1cb-620054bc5db5
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.94 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Referer: http://Mysite/pages/ui/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: he-IL,he;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4,fr;q=0.2
Host: load-rec-8
```

Second results for page X (which is on the 2nd thread group):

```js
GET http://Mysite/pages/MyView.aspx?subRoute=views&pageid=7168&routeName=dashboards

[no cookies]

Request Headers:
Connection: keep-alive
X-DevTools-Emulate-Network-Conditions-Client-Id: 08a74297-b666-496a-a1cb-620054bc5db5
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.94 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Referer: http://Mysite/pages/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: he-IL,he;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4,fr;q=0.2
Host: load-rec-8
```

Please don't answer with "don't use different thread groups" since I have to use only 1 login (1st thread group) while the 2nd thread group should run the same request for 6 users in parallel at the same time.

Whatever tests I did with lots of other posts about this subject didn't work.

Any idea please?

Comment: Are you sure that ThreadGroup2 starts once the ThreadGroup1 sets the cookie property? ?If not, Can you delay threadgroup2 & see if it helps?

Comment: @vins, Yes, since I've set the **Run Thread Groups consecutively (i.e. run groups one at a time)** option in the Test Plan level.
I've also added log.info prints to Thread Group2 and saw that the cookies are created correctly...

Answer (score 1):

Most probably your problem is that you don't provide "domain" when creating a new cookie instance, you need to pass the domain which matches your application under test location (what you have in the "Server Name or IP" section of the [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler), i.e. if you are load testing `http://example.com` domain, provide `.example.com` when you are creating the cookie via Beanshell

In general given you copy cookie names and values, you can also copy all the remaining attributes as well. See [How to Use BeanShell: JMeter's Favorite Built-in Component](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) for example code.

Other enhancements:

1. Replace `${COOKIE_.ASPXAUTH}` with `vars.get("COOKIE_.ASPXAUTH")`;
2. Below lines can be removed, they are not required, Beanshell PreProcessor already has `sampler` pre-defined variable

   ```
   import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy;
   HTTPSamplerProxy sampler = ctx.getCurrentSampler();
   ```

Comment: I actually used WireShark to check the network packets and saw that the domain used is the machine itself - it's testing environment so my URL looks like: **http:// SiteName:80/MySite/...etc...**, so when I've created the cookies, I set location as "/" or even "/MySite" and for domain I set "*SiteName*". But still, it's not working :(